# Error in using same Android Studio SDK for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, facebook-android-sdk, android-sdk-tools

When i was giving the same sdk path in eclipse it gives me this error.Tell how to handle it???

[2015-08-27 11:26:51 - Android SDK] Error when loading the SDK:

> Error: Error parsing C:\Users\Faraz
>   Tariq\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\x86\devices.xml
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.

Comment: what is your sdk location?